# RIghtFax Esoteric error message in .NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1, rightfax

I have a problem with RightFax component Interop.RFCOMAPILib.dll version 1.0.0.0 , using VB .NET 1.1.

It works in several environments, but not in Production.

It returns this message in the exception - "?" - .

How can I solve it? I couldn't find any solution in manuals or on the internet.

Comment: @mtb It is best not to edit things like error messages - it could be that the double-quotes are part of the error message, and would, say, distinguish between a numerical error and a string error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remembers rightfax and lack of information on the internet. this is no answer to your question but one could switch to the builtin windows 2003 fax server with dedicated isdn fax board, has automatic mailforwarding

Comment: Thanks, but i' dont have the power to switch to windows 2003 fax server, i could switch to .net 2.0 or 3.5 too, but are expensive and long time solutions, my customer uses Rightfax in several aplications and i have to solve their problem.